# GRUB2 menu only shown after Ctrl+Alt+Del

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, dual-boot

After finally getting GRUB to see my win8 installment, I decided to tackle my other GRUB2 issue. The GRUB menu only comes up if i press CAD during a blank magenta splash screen that appears during boot where the GRUB menu should be. After I press CAD my computer reboots and then I can see the GRUB menu. How can I set it so that the GRUB menu always shows up?
I already tried commenting out GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 and also changing the value. 
I also tried changing the value of GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply change in grub2, you have to

```
update-grub2
```

to have effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. And I found out I had to comment out both "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET" and "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT"